# Space between tableview cell swiping icon in swift

Tags: swift, tableview

In my code when i am swiping tableview cell, the icons are looking like they are overlapping each other. But i want some space between these icons.
My code:-

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration?{
        let inboxAction =  UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "", handler: { (action,view,completionHandler ) in
            //do stuff
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Swipe", bundle: nil)
            let selectParentProfile = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "InboxViewController") as? InboxViewController
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(selectParentProfile!, animated: true)
            completionHandler(true)
        })
        // create action for the delete button
        let cgImageXq = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: 110, height: 120)).image { _ in
            UIImage(named: "inbox")?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 110, height: 120))
        }
        inboxAction.image = cgImageXq
        //create action for the block button
        let filesAction =  UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "", handler: { (action,view,completionHandler ) in
            //do stuff
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Swipe", bundle: nil)
            let selectParentProfile = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PdfFilesViewController") as? PdfFilesViewController
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(selectParentProfile!, animated: true)
            
            completionHandler(true)
        })
        let cgImageY = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 120)).image { _ in
            UIImage(named: "eval-form")?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 120))
        }
        filesAction.image = cgImageY
        //create action for the block button
        let browserAction =  UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "", handler: { (action,view,completionHandler ) in
            //do stuff
            let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Form", bundle: nil)
            let folderTableViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "FormForPdfViewController")
            
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(folderTableViewController, animated: true)
            
        })
        let cgImageZ = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 120)).image { _ in
            UIImage(named: "pdf-files")?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 120))
        }
        browserAction.image = cgImageZ
        // Add both the delete button and add button here
        let confrigation = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [browserAction, filesAction, inboxAction])
        confrigation.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false
        return confrigation
    }
```

[image]

and also by clicking on the icon i can navigate to another viewcontroller. but when i am coming back to this viewcontroller, still the icon options are showing, but i need to close the swiping option during navigation.

Comment: You have some pathways of code that never calls `completion(true)`. You _must_ call it at the end of _every_ pathway that your code can take. That is what causes the swiped cell to return to normal.

Comment: thanks @matt now swiped cell is returning  to normal in every case. please help me how to make space between the icons

Comment: They overlap because you have not swiped far enough to the left.